# Issue when using a windows process in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, arduino

I'm trying to do a program in Qt Creator, where I want to update an .hex file to arduino. I already did this program in C#, but I'm having some issues when calling the avrdude in QT. I've tried two options:

My first try:

```
process = new QProcess(this);
process->start("avrdude -Cavrdude.conf.txt -v -v -v -v -patmega328p -arduino -PCOM7 -b115200 -D -Uflash:w:Blink.cpp.hex:i", 0);
process->waitForFinished(-1);

QByteArray stdout = process.readAllStandardOutput();
QByteArray stderr = process->readAllStandardError();
```

My second try:

```
QString exePath = "avrdude";
QString arguments = "-Cavrdude.conf.txt -v -v -v -v -patmega328p -carduino -PCOM7 -b115200 -D -Uflash:w:Blink.cpp.hex:i";
#ifdef Q_OS_WIN32
ShellExecuteW(NULL, NULL, (LPCWSTR)exePath.toStdWString().data(), (LPCWSTR)arguments.toStdWString().data(), NULL, SW_HIDE);
#endif
```

I'd like to know if someone has any idea why my code is doing nothing, or some solution that I can use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is `avrdude` in the path? If it is not you can call the [`setWorkingDirectory`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#setWorkingDirectory) before executing the process or add it to the path. In order to check it, open the command line, `cd` into the binary folder of your `Qt` application and enter the command:

`avrdude -Cavrdude.conf.txt -v -v -v -v -patmega328p -arduino -PCOM7 -b115200 -D -Uflash:w:Blink.cpp.hex:i", 0`

Did it run? If not what is the error you got?

You can also use the [`error`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#ProcessError-enum) function to get the last error.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try [this one](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#execute):

```
QProcess::execute( /*program*/, /*arguments*/ );
```

Comment: Thank you, but I still have the problem, i think that may be something related to the exe file location, or something like that. I put it in the same folder os the realese code, however it´s not working.

Comment: What is return code ? `int code = QProcess::execute( ... )` maybe it will help you.

Comment: I got this error: C:\Users\Vinicius\OneDrive\ExpanseSky\AstropilotFirmwareUpdater\mainwindow.cpp:17: error: C2665: 'QProcess::execute' : none of the 2 overloads could convert all the argument types
c:\qt\5.4\msvc2013_64\include\qtcore\qprocess.h(203): could be 'int QProcess::execute(const QString &,const QStringList &)'
while trying to match the argument list '(const char [8], const char [99])'

Comment: The first argument shall be a `QString` and the second is `QStringList`. `QProcess::execute( "exe", QStringList() << "arguments" )`.